# I don't understand how the second bracket works

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This piece of code is for plotting a series of data by coloring by the classes they belong to. `X_train` is an array `(115,2)` and `Y_train` is another array `(115,)` with their respective scope values. My question is what does `[Y_train == i]` do exactly?

```
colors = ["red", "greenyellow", "blue"]
for i in range(len(colors)):
    xs = X_train[:, 0][Y_train == i]
    ys = X_train[:,1][Y_train == i]
    plt.scatter(xs, ys, c = colors[i])

plt.legend(iris.target_names)
plt.xlabel("Sepal length")
plt.ylabel("Sepal width")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a comparison in NumPy, such as `Y_train == i` the result is a boolean mask, that is an array containing `True` for every entry in the array when the value matches `i`, and `False` for every other value.

So, for example, with a simple array like:

```
y = np.array([1,2,1,3])
```

If you look at `y == 1` the result is:

```
array([True, False, True, False])
```

In the case of a simple array:

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
x
Out[10]: 
    array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4],
           [5, 6],
           [7, 8]])
```

You are first slicing one column at a time, for example:

```
x[:, 0]
Out[11]: array([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

And then applying the boolean mask, which returns only the values in that column that also have `True` in the `y == 1` boolean mask:

```
x[:, 0][y == 1]
Out[14]: array([1, 5])
```

So the above has exactly the same result as:

```
x[:, 0][[True, False, True, False]]
Out[16]: array([1, 5])
```

Answer (score 4):

Boolean values in python are just subclasses of integers.

`Y_train == i` just evaluates into either `False` or `True`, which is then used to access either index `0` or `1` respectively.

```py
>>> a = ['this string is at index 0', 'this string is at index 1']
>>> a[True]
'this string is at index 1'
>>> a[False]
'this string is at index 0'
>>> a[1 + 2 == 3]  # true
'this string is at index 1'
```